# Cannot Pass C# Dictionary to ironPython method as parameter

Tags: c#, python, dictionary, parameters, ironpython

i need to pass a parameter list stored in a dictionary to a function
implemented by an ironPython class.

I have prepared the minimum example that reproduces the error:

```
        // C# Side
        var runtime = Python.CreateRuntime();
        dynamic test = runtime.UseFile("test.py");

        // Here the parameters dictionary is instantiated and filled
        var parametersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        parametersDictionary.Add("first", 1);

        // The Python 'x' instance is called passing parameter dictionary
        var result = test.x.ReturnFirstParameter(parametersDictionary);
```

Now the Python code:

```
# Python side

# Class 'Expression' definition
class Expression(object):
    def ReturnFirstParameter(self, **parameters):
        return parameters['first']

# Class 'Expression' instantiation
x = Expression()
```

When i run the program, i get the following exception:

```
ReturnFirstParameter() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

The first parameter is 'self', but it seems like ignoring it receives
2 parameters, 'self' and the dictionary.

I have tried changing the dictionary for other parameters and it works well. The problem
only arises when you receive a ** parameter.

I deeply appreciate your help!

Esteban.

Comment: The `**` is special Python syntax (collect all keyword arguments into a dict), I don't know if you can use it from C#. Why do you need it?

Comment: Thanks Nklas, it worked! I guess the class Dictionary is defined inside IronPhyton framework, and received as a reference. I tought it converted the C# dictionary to whatever ** python type is, but not the case. Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering if you could pass an immutable dictionary like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work to simply remove the `**` from in front of `parameters` in the Python code:

```
class Expression(object):
    def ReturnFirstParameter(self, parameters):
        return parameters['first']
```

`**` should be used when you are passing in named parameters to a function, and your C# code will be passing a dictionary.

Your C# code would call the function like this:

```
x.ReturnFirstParameter({'first': 1})
```

For it to work with `**parameters` the call would need to be

```
x.ReturnFirstParameter(first=1)
```

There may be a way to do this with ironpython but I'm not sure how.